# Want to creat a search for my wordpress theme

Tags: search, search-engines

im new in wordpress , i've made my first theme
and i need your help guys , i want to creat a search for my theme

this is my search form :
searchform.php

```
<div class="search-home">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <input class="schome" type="text" id="search-box" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="find your favorite game">
        <button> search </button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

what should i do pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses the `s` key for search. If you add `name="s"` to the input field this would probably work out of the box.
Also make sure the button element has `type="submit"` so your browser knows this is the submit button.